# How set graphql-js module in debug mode

Tags: javascript, server, graphql, graphql-js

i'm new in graphql and setting up server graphql api use [https://github.com/graphql/graphql-js] `graphql-js`.

I followed their document and everything work, expect 1 problem:

- when make query and got error from deep module, `graphql-js` try catch error and return result with `errors: [...]` property, but in terminal console say nothing. I would like force `grahql-js` return actual Error object so i can debug issue when looking to stack.

this is code in api

```
query: (ctx) -> (
      await graphql(
        schema
        query
        context
        graphContext
        variables
      )
    )
```

I search a lot of topic but no ones say about set this package in debug mode, also no see any parameter allow set debug. Anyone know about this?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Normally, you would use a library like `express-graphql` or `apollo-server` (or `apollo-server-express`, `apollo-server-hapi`, etc.) to provide an endpoint for your GraphQL API. Unless your use case prohibits you from doing so, I would strongly encourage you to utilize one of these libraries since they provide a number of additional features that are helpful in both development and production.

You can add logging to your endpoint when using one of these libraries simply by providing a custom `formatError` function in your configuration. See each library's documentation [here](https://github.com/graphql/express-graphql#options) and [here](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/features/errors.html#Masking-and-logging-errors). As a bonus, if you use Apollo, then the full stack trace will be exposed inside of your `errors` array anyway, but only in development.

If you're calling the `graphql` function directly in your code somewhere, then you can just log the errors yourself. The call to `graphql` returns a Promise that resolves to a ExecutionResult object, which includes both your data and errors. So you can do something like:

```
const result = await graphql(/* your args */)
if (result.errors) {
  result.errors.forEach((error) => {
    // log the error
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to instantiate the graph object with the debug option enabled, like this

```
var graph = graphql("/api", { debug: true })
```